# multiple elements in 1 Angular directive

Tags: angularjs-directive

To do the classic HTML5 draw video frames one by one in canvas you need to access 2 elements in same block of code eg in a directive:

```
link:function(scope,element){
var ctx = element[0].getContext('2d');
var videoE1 = element[0].children[0].children[0];
function draw() {
ctx.drawImage(videoE1,0,0,720,480);
}
```

Can this be done in Angularjs or later versions?